On a notion of asymptotically monotone sequence
Let us say that an infinite sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers is asymptotically increasing if there exists a double sequence
$\{b_{n,m}\}_{n<m}$ such that
(1) $b_{n,m}\rightarrow 0$ as $n,m \rightarrow \infty$, that is, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for all $m>n>N$ one has $|b_{n,m}|<\varepsilon$.
(2) $a_n\leq (1+b_{n,m})a_m$ whenever $n<m$.
(I don't know whether this is a standard definition, but that's the definition that suits my purposes.) So, when all $b_{n,m}$ are zero, we get the definition of (non-strictly) increasing sequence.
My question is: Is it true that an asymptotically increasing sequence (in the above sense) which is bounded is convergent?

Just to confirm, $b_{n,m}$ corresponds to the function $b : X \to \mathbb R$, where $X  = {(n,m) \mid n \in \mathbb N, m \in \mathbb N, n < m}$, correct?

@mhdadk , yes, that's correct.

Choose $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, and then $N$ corresponding to $\epsilon$ as in (1). By (2),
$$
a_n\le (1+\epsilon) a_m,\qquad\forall m>n>N.
$$
Therefore
$$
a_n\le(1+\epsilon)\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m,\qquad\forall n>N.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n\le(1+\epsilon)\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m.
$$
As this is true for each $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, you have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n\le \liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m.
$$
Therefore, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n= \liminf_{m\to\infty}a_m$, so the sequence $(a_n)$ converges in the extended real line; the potential limits $\pm\infty$ are ruled out by the boundedness of $(a_n)$.
